# Adding textbox dynamically and save values to the database in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net

I would like to add text box dynamically by clicking add button , can delete text box and finally can save the list values from the text boxes .
My model class

```
public class CustModel
{
    public List<Cust> CustList { get; set; }
}

public class Cust
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
My controller class


public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private DB _entities;

        public HomeController()
        {
            _entities = new DbEntities();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
                return View(_customers);

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(CustModel model)
        {
                // save to the database
                return View();

        }
   }
```

I want to know .cshtml code . Or any other suggestion to submit list item to the database .

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I would do it:

In the CustModel, I will change the property to IEnumerable. I will use EditorTemplate for Cust and this will save extra looping.

```
public class CustModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Cust> CustList { get; set; }
}
```

My Index.cshtml view is vary simple, I have declared strongly typed model, then in the form I have `@Html.EditorFor` for Custlist, a button to add new cust, a button to submit and JQuery script to add new cust. Notice that in the jquery I am creating array of controls so that model binder can pick them properly.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.CustModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div id="divcust">
            @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.CustList)
        </div>
        <input id="btnAdd"  type="button" value="Add Cust" onclick="AddCust();" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
}
<script>
    function AddCust() {
        var m = $('#divcust input:last-child').attr('name');
        var index = 0;
        if (m != null && m.length > 0) {
            index = m.split('CustList[')[1].replace('].Name', '');
            index++;
        }

        var html = '<label for=\"CustList_' + index + '__Name\">Name</label>' +
            '<input id=\"CustList_' + index + '__Name\" class=\"text-box single-line\"' +
            ' type=\"text\" value=\"\" name=\"CustList[' + index + '].Name\">';
        $('#divcust').append(html);


    };
</script>
```

I have added a EditorTemplates folder in my view/home folder and added a view for Cust:

**Cust.cshtml**

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Cust

@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Name)
```

Everything works fine now, I can add new Custs and post them to save.

[image]

If I want to add delete function, I have to be careful to keep integrity of my control array.

Comment: <button onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)">Delete</button>function RemoveTextBox(button) {
            $(button).parent().remove();
        }

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to dyamically generate UI, implement Validation and posting form values to controller which can easily stored into database.

```
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.js" integrity="sha512-8Z5++K1rB3U+USaLKG6oO8uWWBhdYsM3hmdirnOEWp8h2B1aOikj5zBzlXs8QOrvY9OxEnD2QDkbSKKpfqcIWw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

            <fieldset>
                <legend></legend>
                <form id="DemoForm">
                    <div id="divcust" class="container">

                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div style="margin-left:30px">
                        <button type="button" name="Submit" onclick="SubmitData()" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                        <button type="button" name="Cancel" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </fieldset>

            <script>

                var substr = {
                    "product": [
                        { "Label": "First Name", "Id": "Name", "type": "text", "Required": "True" },
                        { "Label": "Age", "Id": "Age", "type": "Number", "Required": "True" },
                        { "Label": "Date of Birth", "Id": "DOB", "type": "date", "Required": "True" },
                        { "Label": "Gender", "Id": "Gender", "type": "select", "Required": "True" },
                        { "Label": "Mobile No", "Id": "Mobile_No", "type": "Number", "Required": "True" },
                        { "Label": "Address 1", "Id": "Address1", "type": "text", "Required": "True" },
                        { "Label": "Address 2", "Id": "Address2", "type": "text", "Required": "False" },
                        { "Label": "Address 3", "Id": "Address3", "type": "text", "Required": "False" },

                        { "Label": "City", "Id": "City", "type": "select", "Required": "True" }
                    ],
                    "DropDown": [
                        { "Key": "Select", "Value": "", "ParentId": "Gender" },
                        { "Key": "Male", "Value": "Male", "ParentId": "Gender" },
                        { "Key": "Female", "Value": "Female", "ParentId": "Gender" },

                        { "Key": "Select", "Value": "", "ParentId": "City" },
                        { "Key": "Mumbai", "Value": "Mumbai", "ParentId": "City" },
                        { "Key": "Thane", "Value": "Thane", "ParentId": "City" },
                        { "Key": "Pune", "Value": "Pune", "ParentId": "City" }
                    ]
                }

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    AddCust();
                    CheckValidation();
                });

                function AddCust() {

                    var html = "";

                    for (var i = 0; i < substr.product.length; i++) {
                        if (substr.product[i].type == "select") {

                            var Dropdown_Values = substr.DropDown.filter(function (item) {
                                return item.ParentId == substr.product[i].Id;
                            });

                            var option = "";
                            Dropdown_Values.forEach(function (item) {
                                option = option + '<option \" class=\"form-control\"' + 'value=\"' + item.Value + '\"> ' +
                                    item.Key + ' </option>'
                            })

                            html = html
                                + '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"> <label for=\"CustList_' + substr.product[i].Id + '__Name\"> ' + substr.product[i].Label + ': <span id=\"Hide_' + substr.product[i].Id + '\" style="color:red" style="display:none" hidden> * </span></label>'
                                + '<select id=\"' + substr.product[i].Id + '\" class=\"form-control\"' + 'name=\"' + substr.product[i].Id + '\"> ' +

                                option

                                + ' </select></div>';
                        }
                        else {
                            html = html
                                + '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"> <label for=\"CustList_' + substr.product[i].Id + '__Name\"> ' + substr.product[i].Label + ': <span id=\"Hide_' + substr.product[i].Id + '\" style="color:red" style="display:none" hidden> * </span></label>'
                                + '<input id=\"' + substr.product[i].Id + '\" class=\"form-control\"' + ' type=\"'
                                + substr.product[i].type + '\" value=\"\" name=\"' + substr.product[i].Id + '\"> </div>';
                        }
                    }

                    $('#divcust').append(html);
                };

                function SubmitData() {

                    var Required_Input = substr.product.filter(function (item) {
                        return item.Required == "True";
                    });

                    var $inputs = $('#DemoForm :input');

                    var Form_values = {};
                    $inputs.each(function () {
                        Form_values[this.name] = $(this).val();
                    });
                    delete Form_values.Submit;
                    delete Form_values.Cancel;

                    for (var i = 0; i < Required_Input.length; i++) {

                        var filtered_Key = "";
                        var filtered_Values = "";
                        var Required_alert = Required_Input[i].Label;
                        var Field = Required_Input[i].Id;
                        const filteredByKey = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(Form_values).filter(([key, value]) => key === Field))

                        for (var key in filteredByKey) {
                            filtered_Key = key;
                            filtered_Values = filteredByKey[key];
                        }

                        if (filtered_Key == Required_Input[i].Id) {

                            if (filtered_Values == "") {
                                alert(Required_alert + " is Required ")
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Save_Data(Form_values);

                }

                function CheckValidation() {
                    var Required_Input = substr.product.filter(function (item) {
                        return item.Required == "True";
                    });

                    for (var i = 0; i < Required_Input.length; i++) {
                        $("#Hide_" + Required_Input[i].Id).show();
                    }
                }

                function Save_Data(Data) {
                    var Common_Set = {};
                    Common_Set.Json_Input = JSON.stringify(Data);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/UserMaster/Save_Data",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify(Common_Set),
                        success: function (result) {
                            // when call is sucessfull
                            alert(JSON.stringify(Data))
                            window.location.reload();
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            // check the err for error details
                        }
                    });

                }

            </script>
```

Comment: you can use this code to dyamically generate UI, implement Validation and posting form values to controller which can easily stored into database.